# If I display a button which triggers a phone call, is it possible to hide from the user the phone number?

Tags: android, ios, phone-call

If I display a button on the screen which allows the see to make a phone call, how can I hide the phone number so that the user is not able to see the number and call again from his call history? I am interested if this is possible on either iOS or Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Even if you could it would show in the dialer and the user's call history. Why the secrecy?